# Capture both exit status and output from a system call in R

Tags: linux, r, system, call

I've been playing a bit with `system()` and `system2()` for fun, and it struck me that I can save either the output or the exit status in an object. A toy example:

```
X <- system("ping google.com",intern=TRUE)
```

gives me the output, whereas

```
X <- system2("ping", "google.com")
```

gives me the exit status (1 in this case, google doesn't take ping). If I want both the output and the exit status, I have to do 2 system calls, which seems a bit overkill. How can I get both with using only one system call?

EDIT : I'd like to have both in the console, if possible without going over a temporary file by using `stdout="somefile.ext"` in the `system2` call and subsequently reading it in.

Comment: Are you using Linux or Windows? I can't even get stdout="somefile.ext" to work on Windows, but it works fine on Linux...

Comment: I recommend adding `linux` to your tags, along with whatever shell you're using.  This can invite some solutions from the OS experts.

Comment: Apologies to OP and @Gavin, I may be mistaken: I thought this was explicitly or implicitly Linux, but I see the OP didn't even mention Linux and it could be another OS for all I know.

Comment: It's not Linux, it's even non OS specific. It's about the R code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As of R 2.15, `system2` will give the return value as an attribute when `stdout` and/or `stderr` are TRUE. This makes it easy to get the text output and return value.

In this example, `ret` ends up being a string with an attribute `"status"`:

```
> ret <- system2("ls","xx", stdout=TRUE, stderr=TRUE)
Warning message:
running command ''ls' xx 2>&1' had status 1 
> ret
[1] "ls: xx: No such file or directory"
attr(,"status")
[1] 1
> attr(ret, "status")
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 13):

I am a bit confused by your description of system2, because it has stdout and stderr arguments. So it is able to return both exit status, stdout and stderr.

```
> out <- tryCatch(ex <- system2("ls","xx", stdout=TRUE, stderr=TRUE), warning=function(w){w})
> out
<simpleWarning: running command ''ls' xx 2>&1' had status 2>
> ex
[1] "ls: cannot access xx: No such file or directory"
> out <- tryCatch(ex <- system2("ls","-l", stdout=TRUE, stderr=TRUE), warning=function(w){w})
> out
 [listing snipped]                  
> ex
 [listing snipped]
```

Comment: +1 Very good.  By the way, welcome to SO, where not everyone reads the help information for R commands.  ;-)

Comment: +1, as it's using R's internal warning and error tricks. I can cut out the exit status from the warning-message. I know I can use stdout=TRUE, but the exit status is my main concern. That's why I didn't do that.

Comment: Seems like the way to do it anyway, so that's going to be the accepted answer.

Comment: When I run the first command (`ls xx`), I get the same warning message for `out`, but `ex` is not set at all. This is with R 2.14.2 on both Mac and Linux. Are there any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 8):

I suggest using this function here:

```
robust.system <- function (cmd) {
  stderrFile = tempfile(pattern="R_robust.system_stderr", fileext=as.character(Sys.getpid()))
  stdoutFile = tempfile(pattern="R_robust.system_stdout", fileext=as.character(Sys.getpid()))

  retval = list()
  retval$exitStatus = system(paste0(cmd, " 2> ", shQuote(stderrFile), " > ", shQuote(stdoutFile)))
  retval$stdout = readLines(stdoutFile)
  retval$stderr = readLines(stderrFile)

  unlink(c(stdoutFile, stderrFile))
  return(retval)
}
```

This will only work on a Unix-like shell that accepts > and 2> notations, and the cmd argument should not redirect output itself. But it does the trick:

```
> robust.system("ls -la")
$exitStatus
[1] 0

$stdout
 [1] "total 160"                                                      
 [2] "drwxr-xr-x  14 asieira  staff    476 10 Jun 18:18 ."            
 [3] "drwxr-xr-x  12 asieira  staff    408  9 Jun 20:13 .."           
 [4] "-rw-r--r--   1 asieira  staff   6736  5 Jun 19:32 .Rapp.history"
 [5] "-rw-r--r--   1 asieira  staff  19109 11 Jun 20:44 .Rhistory"    

$stderr
character(0)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great!  This really should be the default functionality in R.