# How to include shell command results in Sweave PDF report?

Tags: r, shell, rstudio, sweave

I need to include the results and reports of shell calls in a Sweave PDF report, but I can't find any parameter for that in the chunk parameters.

For example, when I apply the code below:

```
> system(" makeblastdb -in mouseX.fasta -dbtype nucl -parse_seqids -out mouseXdb")
```

It reports:

```
Building a new DB, current time: 05/01/2015 18:31:57
New DB name:   mouseXdb
New DB title:  mouseX.fasta
Sequence type: Nucleotide
Keep Linkouts: T
Keep MBits: T
Maximum file size: 1000000000B
Adding sequences from FASTA; added 1 sequences in 1.08783 seconds.
```

but it doesn't show up in Sweave Report when I use parameters like print or echo...

As another example, I might want to include the header of a file in my report using a shell call to the header command.

Comment: Did you try using `rep <- system(...,intern = TRUE)` and then print `rep`?
Maybe this helps

Comment: @Floo0 sorry but not working... it returns zero...

Comment: Does [this previous SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014081/capture-both-exit-status-and-output-from-a-system-call-in-r) answer your question?

Comment: @Jthorpe Unfortunately No .. I want the execution message not the output of the system call, when i done that, it just take me a null character